# can't fetch another git repo using .gitmodules in gitlab-ci

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I try build pipeline using gitlab-ci to generate set of micro-services jars and start with independent service as trial but .gitmodules file don't work correctly i configure it as [gitlab-doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html#using-git-submodules-in-your-ci-jobs) explained

here is my `.gitmodules`  file

```
[submodule "logging-service"]
    path = logging-service
    branch = develop
    url = ../logging-service
```

and here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
stages:
  - maven_build
  - test_coverage
  - sonar_qube
  - deploy_cf_critical_services_dev
  - deploy_cf_rest_of_services_dev
  - postman_tests

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  SONAR_URL: http://localhost:9000
  SONAR_USERNAME: admin
  SONAR_PASSWORD: admin

sonar_qube_phase_logging-service:
  image: sonarqube:latest
  stage: sonar_qube
  script: 
    - mvn -f sonar:sonar logging-service/pom.xml -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_USERNAME -Dsonar.password=$SONAR_PASSWORD

test_coverage_phase_logging-service:
  image: dockerproxy-iva.si.francetelecom.fr/maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
  stage: test_coverage
  script: 
    - mvn clean verify -f ../logging-service/pom.xml

maven_build_phase_logging-service:
  image: dockerproxy-iva.si.francetelecom.fr/maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
  stage: maven_build
  script: 
    - mvn install -f logging-service/pom.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
  artifacts:
    name: logging-service #jar name 
    paths:
      - logging-service/target
    expire_in: 1 day
```

and error generated from maven can't find pom.xml in path 
error path

```
/builds/ole_bothub/bothub-deployment-dev/logging-service/pom.xml
```

and the path should be like the following

```
/builds/ole_bothub/logging-service/pom.xml
```

and here is log of maven_build_phase_logging-service job

```
 Updating/initializing submodules recursively...

$ mvn install -f logging-service/pom.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
 [FATAL] Non-readable POM /builds/ole_bothub/bothub-deployment-dev/logging-service/pom.xml: /builds/ole_bothub/bothub-deployment-dev/logging-service/pom.xml (No such file or directory) @ 
  @ 
 [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR]   
 [ERROR]   The project  (/builds/ole_bothub/bothub-deployment-dev/logging-service/pom.xml) has 1 error
 [ERROR]     Non-readable POM /builds/ole_bothub/bothub-deployment-dev/logging-service/pom.xml: /builds/ole_bothub/bothub-deployment-dev/logging-service/pom.xml (No such file or directory)
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by delete .gitmodules file and create another one using `git-CLI` by the following step

- clone separate **ci-repo** to my local machine
  `git clone <repo_ci_URL>`
- start to add submodules using git-cli
  `git submodule add <referenced_repo>`
- commit changes to my **ci-repo**
  `git commit -m "mys message"`
- repeat previous step to all git repos I want to add to my ci pipeline
- finally push changes to your **ci-repo**

and start my pipeline and everything work well to me.